# changing streams in C language

Tags: c

i want to know how i can change my program current stream?
i mean i want to get my input from a file.

Comment: What do you mean 'stream' - stdio/out/err? or something else?

Comment: Please provide more details about what you're trying to do.  This question is too vague to answer and will likely be closed.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're talking about standard C I/O streams as represented by the FILE * objects stdin and stdout, you can use [freopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen):

```
/* Change stdin to read from the given file. */
freopen("funny-input.txt", "rt", stdin);
```

Comment: i agree with your idea but i did this (for copying a file to another file) but i faced nothing however my friend write his program as same as mine and it worked well.

Comment: @amin: Edit the question to include some of the code you tried that didn't work, if you want help figuring out exactly why it didn't work.

Comment: `"rt"` mode "read *turbo*"? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a program like this:

```
#include <stdio>
int main(int ac, char **av) {
    int i;
    if(scanf("%d", &i) == 1)
        printf("Answer: %d\n", i);
    else
        printf("No answer\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and you want to "change your current stream". In addition to the "freopen" option listed elsewhere, you might want to redirect your input. If you use a shell (UNIX) or a console windows (WINDOWS) to invoke your program:

```
C:\> MYPROG.EXE
```

instead, invoke it thusly

```
C:\> MYPROG.EXE < INPUTFILE.TXT
```

In that case, all of the input to `stdin` (for example, `scanf`, `getchar`, etc) will come from the file named `INPUTFILE.TXT` instead of your keyboard.

Alternatively, you could open the file in your program:

```
#include <stdio>
int main(int ac, char **av) {
    FILE *input;
    int i;

    input = fopen("INPUTFILE.TXT", "r");
    if(!input) {
        printf("No input file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(fscanf(input, "%d", &i) == 1)
        printf("Answer: %d\n", i);
    else
        printf("No answer\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you have opened the new input file, and you use the resulting handle in subsequent calls. Also note that you have to use slightly different calls to read from a specified handle instead of `stdin`. For example, you must use `fscanf` instead of `scanf`, `getc` instead of `getchar`, and `fgets` instead of `gets`.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) is used to change the assignment of an already open file stream.  It is in C89 standard C - though the link is to a POSIX standard.